# AWS Ubuntu Virtual Directory for Angular 2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I just finished installing angular 2 on an unbuntu server from AWS. My problem is when I goto my server in the browser example.com I get the Ubuntu index.html page, when I got my angular 2 project example.com/myapp/dist/browser/ I get a bunch of 404 errors because for css and js files because its trying to get them from the root example.com/assets/css/style.css

My question is how do I get example.com to be my angular 2 project?

Here is my VirtualHost from laravel.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/myapp/dist/dist/browser>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```